# ClassNotFoundException when deploying multi-module POM project (EAR) to WTP

Tags: eclipse, maven, ear, pom.xml, eclipse-wtp

**Eclipse version:** Indigo

**Target Application server:** Weblogic 10.3.5 (11gR1)

I am having trouble building and deploying a multi-module POM project (packaged as an EAR) to my WebLogic server, within Eclipse.

Despite the parent POM building an EAR file successfully outside of the IDE, I am receiving the following error when trying to deploy the UI WAR to the Application Server:

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:190)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:486)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1466)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:898)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:686)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3027)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'lerp-ui'
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:393)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:613)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:184)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet

    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processServlets(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:225)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processJ2eeAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:209)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:105)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processAnnotations(WebAppServletContext.java:1368)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:449)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:493)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:972)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:382)
```

This is despite having the jsf-api dependency in both the Maven POM and referenced in the .classpath file for the UI WAR project:

**Snippet of the POM for the UI WAR project:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

**.classpath for UI WAR Project:**

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/faces/jsf-api/2.0.3/jsf-api-2.0.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.0.3/jsf-impl-2.0.3.jar"/>
```

**Below follows the entire parent POM of the multi-module project:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>uk.co.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>multiModulePOMProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>acme troublesome project</name>


    <modules>
        <module>../../Business/common</module>
        <module>../../Business/svccom</module>
        <module>../../Business/busctl</module>
        <module>../../Client/ui</module>
        <module>../../Business/ear</module>
        <module>../../Business/talend/java/businessrules</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        
        <project.ui.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</project.ui.version>
        <project.common.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</project.common.version>
        <project.svccom.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</project.svccom.version>
        <project.busctl.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</project.busctl.version>
                        
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <webapp.filter>development</webapp.filter>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>      
        <eclipselink.version>2.1.3</eclipselink.version>
        <persistence.version>2.0.0</persistence.version>
        <spring.cdi.version>1.0.0</spring.cdi.version>
        
        <weblogic.adminurl>t3://localhost:7050</weblogic.adminurl>
        <weblogic.user>weblogic</weblogic.user>
        <weblogic.password>welcome1</weblogic.password>
        <weblogic.target>acmeLocalDomain</weblogic.target>
        <weblogic.source>../../Business/ear/target/${parent.artifactId}.${packaging}</weblogic.source>              
        
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <webapp.filter>production</webapp.filter>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It's clear that this is some classpathing issue, but I have gone scrollbind from staring at it over the course of two days and have decided that the time has come to wave the white flag and appeal for help!

The end goal is to take my EAR project (which currently is hampered from an annoying need to undeploy/redeploy on the command line for every little change) and get it so that I can perform hot fixes within a deployment which is run inside the IDE.

Thanks

**Update:**

By adding the offending dependency to the `domains\<domain>\lib` folder of the application server, and restarting the application server, I have now started getting `ClassNotFoundExceptions` for other WAR dependencies. It is clear now that Eclipse is not respecting the `classpath` of the WAR project - and I still don't understand why or how :-(

Comment: m2e installed? m2e for wtp installed ? If yes which version? Possible to upgrade to Juno ?

Comment: M2E v1.0.100.20110804-1717, WTP 3.3.1. Unfortunately cannot upgrade to Juno - am throttled by IT to use the version of Indigo supplied with Oracle WebLogic 10.3.5 (11gR1), which is v3.7.1.

Comment: Have correctly imported the Maven project into Eclipse but the .classpath does not look like this.

Comment: I may have manipulated the classpath by running the eclipse:eclipse install command. I am still unsure as to how the Maven plugin may be fighting M2E

Comment: I have made some progress which isolates the problem further and posted an update at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To package dependencies into your `lib` directory, add this to your `EAR` packaging `pom`:

```xml
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.5</version>
         <configuration>
            <version>6</version>
            <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
            <modules>
               [Your EJB and Web modules here]
            </modules>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Notice the `defaultLibBundleDir` tag.

Answer (score 0):

After building the EAR using `File > Export` in Eclipse, I was able to compare the EAR to the one produced by my Maven POM.

I found that Eclipse did not contain references to the Maven Dependencies build path items in the Deployment Assembly (I discovered that simply adding the Projects as dependencies wasn't enough).

Reading around the subject, I found that it was neccessary to add the Maven Dependencies of the child WAR and JARs to their respective WAR and JAR projects, but with a destination of

> ../lib

This is declared **on each WAR and JAR** refers to **the lib folder of the parent EAR.**

Using a combination of this menu (and alternatively by editing each of the corresponding .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component files for each affected WAR and JAR in turn) I was able to build up a version of the EAR which matched the one produced via my Maven script.

I hope this helps someone.